# Geometry problem by isi 2016

Tags: geometry

Let ABCD be a square two of whose adjacent vertices, say A, B are on the positive x axis and positive y axis. If C has co-ordinates (u,v) in the first quadrant, determine the area ABCD in terms of u and v.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Edit your question to provide that information and you will probably get some help.

Comment: I applied all the properties of square but could not eliminate the assumed variables in form of u and v

Answer (score 6):

[image: ![enter image description here]

Due to similar triangles, we have:

$u = y$

$v = y + x = u + x$

And $s^2$ is the area of $ABCD$.

Therefore, $s^2 = x^2 + y^2 = (v-u)^2 + u^2 = v^2 - 2 u v + 2 u^2$

Comment: The diagram ( and hence results derived) you've used are of the square ABDC, not ABCD as the question states. The correction is a triviality, but just thought I'd mention it here.

Comment: @TimTheEnchanter Fixed

Answer (score 2):

Let $A=(x,0)$ and $B=(0,y)$.
Then $C=(0,y)+(y,x)=(y,x+y)$.

Therefore, $u=y$ and $v=x+y$. Then $x=v-u$ and $y=u$.

The area of $ABCD$ is $AB^2=x^2+y^2=(v-u)^2+u^2=v^2-2uv+2u^2$.

Comment: Please explain how did u write C in x and y

Comment: congruence triangles.

Comment: Let $E$ be the point which is vertical below $C$ and is on the right of $B$. Then $\triangle OAB\cong \triangle ECB$ ($O$ is the origin). Thus $EB=OB=y$ and $EC=OA=x$.

Comment: Ya !! Got it thanks